# VLC - specifying debugging option and log file doesn't work

Tags: vlc, logging, debug

I am trying to display an mp4-file using vlc. I have specified the verbosity level as 2 (debug) and a log file name of ~/vlc.log. When I run vlc, it does NOT display my slideshow. Nevertheless, I cannot see anything in the log file. Any ideas?